# O2 optimization level breaks program work

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-optimization

I have a C++ project that was originally written in Visual Studio for Windows. It contains calls to Intel MKL and some OMP code. There different vector and matrix operations. I have tested it both in release and debug in VS both in Microsoft and Intel compiler on windows without any problems.

I have ported it on Linux using Eclipse and Intel C++ compiler. In debug configuration tests are passed, but when I am changing optimization level from Disabled (-O0) to MaximizeSpeed(-O2). Tests begin failing, somewhere computations produce different results(~10%). What can be the reason why the same Intel compiler on Linux produces different results with enabled optimization? Any ideas to check?

Comment: If changing the optimization level breaks your program then your program most likely has bugs. I'd guess it contains Undefined Behaviour that the compiler ends up exploiting in unfortunate ways. A *correct* program should never change behaviour when optimized, but a broken one most likely *will*. Provide a [mcve] please, then we can help you better.

Comment: How are you determining if results are "different"?  Do you have a range of expected values, or are you looking for a specific exact bit pattern?  `-ffast-math` definitely can cause changes in the last bit or two -- these changes are very tiny and shouldn't have any real world effect.

Comment: @Ben Voigt specifically about `-ffast-math` (which breaks standard mandated behaviour btw) - those *slight* differences you mention *can* matter. I work on a application that's classed as a "medical device" and we used to use `-ffast-math` but don't any more since we need *strict* IEEE754 behaviour for some calculations and the errors `-ffast-math` introduced turned out to be significant for our results. `-ffast-math` *breaks* stuff in some situations that are not all irrelevant.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Obviously you know the details of your own project, but I tend to think that if `-ffast-math` magnitude errors are affecting results, there's a design problem, because usually you have even larger errors due to sensor noise.  For example, if you're locating the maximum in an array, `-ffast-math` could break a (to-significant-precision) tie in a different direction from strict IEEE and cause a very different index to be chosen... but it's a design fault for allowing a tie in the first place.

Comment: *"...  why the same Intel compiler on Linux produces different results with enabled optimization"* - ICC is ruthless and removes undefined behavior. On Linux compile, use GCC or Clang and compile with `-fsanitize=undefined`. Then clear the findings and retest with ICC. On Linux you are aiming for `-O3`. That's where the program really speeds up due to vectorizations and use of functions like AVX memcpy. But you have to remove the UB to get there.

Comment: found the reason. That was a bug in Eigen library swap function

Answer (score 2):

possible reasons:

As Jesper already pointed out in the comments, propably your program has undefined behavior leading to different results.

Other, less likeley possibility is a compiler bug - check if you use a up-to date compiler version and/or try another compiler.

I'd recommend in decending order:

- enable all warnings for your compiler (check and fix issues if
  applicable)
- check if you use a up-to date compiler
- run some static code analyzer (e.g. cppcheck)
- try different compiler

Comment: Plus, check if your Intel compiler has the same version on Linux as on Windows. The compiler versions provided by package maintainers tend to be older ones....

Comment: Also, trying `valgrind` might be useful.